# Orion Context Broker stops responding after some hours

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

This error occurred with v. 0.11.0 of the Orion Context Broker.

I've been running an instance of the Orion Context Broker in the FIWARE Testbed, and after some hours, the Orion Context Broker simply stops responding. However, it does not crash, that is, when querying the status of the context broker with the command:

```
/etc/init.d/contextBroker status
```

it will respond with "Running".

However, it does not respond to any http requests issued towards it. For example, the sanity check run directly on the VM with the context broker will fail:

```
wget http://localhost:1026/version
```

Stopping and starting orion or restarting orion, does not resolve the issue. Restarting the linux VM itself, resolves the issue, until it stops working again with the same issue.

I'm running with a constant activity of about 40 entities with a total of about 100 different attributes. I have on average ~100 attributes that are updated every 5 second and this is encapsulated in about 1-40 requests, send at the same time towards the updateContext operation of the Orion Context Broker.

I currently have a single subscriber that subscribes to the ONCHANGE event on ALL attributes for ALL entities (using a regular expression).

I am still able to connect to the VM through SSH, however, it feels less responsive after a while, which leads me to believe it is probably some sort of a memory leak.

Also, as time passes when running updateContext requests towards the broker, these start to feel less and less responsive. (That is, just after restarting the broker, all operations always finish very quickly, however, after a while, it takes a bit longer for them to finish).

I will be able to provide extra information if requested.

**EDIT: Detailed usage statistics**

We run ~20 updateContext requests towards the context broker every 5 seconds. These requests are sent in parallel. Each request has 1 context element with 5-20 attributes (rough estimate!). The contextValue is each of these is a complex value that looks like:

```
<Measurement>
  <Value>20.53</Value>
  <Timestamp>2014-05-08T18:03:00Z</Timestamp>
</Measurement>
```

We run a single subscriber that initially subscribes against the context broker for 10 minutes on ALL entities and all attributes using a regular expression. We update the subscription every 5 minutes to maintain it while the application is alive. (using the update subscription operation).

We do not use any synchronous operations to query context data at all.

We run the context broker on the FIWARE Testbed with HW configuration:

```
RAM:  4096MB
VCPUs:  2 VCPU
Disk:  10GB
```

And it is running on CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a sympton of the spontaneous binary corruption problems documented in the Installation & Administration manual.

Please, have a look to the "Diagnose spontaneous binary corruption problems" section at https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Diagnosis_Procedures section in order to check it.

**EDIT**: the binary corruption seems to be caused by prelink software. We have added information to the above link on how to disable prelink permanently to avoid this problem.

**EDIT**: from Orion 0.14.1, the prelink exclusion file is included in the RPM, so this problem should not happen any longer.

Comment: The md5sum does not seem to match any of the versions: 08aeee1b6bc39a9790d6638785af77cf

Comment: After re-install according to procedure on the page the md5sum is: f38fd28f1f4bac3457444d4063f979f4 (v. 0.12.0, which was released very recently)

Comment: I dont really feel the other symptom: Orion Context Broker send empty responses, matches very well. It does not send empty responses, it does not respond at all.

Comment: @MikaelGuldborg, you mean that after re-installing with 0.12.0 the problem disapeared or you are still having it?

Comment: I have re-installed it, and like when restarting the linux VM, it is currently working. However, I am not currently putting any activity on it because we are doing some data migration. Once this effort has been completed I will start using it again. I will inform you here once I know if the issue has been resolved or if it appears again once we start using it.

Comment: I've started the context broker using the new version (0.12.0) and it has stopped working with the same problem as before. The md5sum has also changed this time: 9935469ed302a90707496d3a0f87a76a.

Comment: @MikaelGuldborg, right md5sum for /usr/bin/contextBroker in 0.12.0 is f38fd28f1f4bac3457444d4063f979f4. Thus, reinstall ("yum remove contextBroker", then "yum install contextBroker"), check the md5sum is right and try again, please. There isn't any (currently known) pattern on why this corruption happens (I'll *very* interested in any clue :), but setting monit to automatically fix contextBroker when it happens (e.g. cp from a master copy to /usr/bin/contextBroker file) is an effective workaround by the time being (check Installation & Administration manual for details).

Comment: I've tried simply re-installing the contextBroker (without resetarting the VM), and although the md5sum is now correct (f38fd28f1f4bac3457444d4063f979f4), it refuses all connections on port 1026.

Comment: @MikaelGuldborg did you restart the CB after reinstalling (/etc/init.d/contextBroker restart)? Some times the process instance corresponding to the old version stays in memory after reinstalling.

Comment: Yes I did, although I did restart it by using the stop command followed by the start command, if that makes a difference. However, having tried restart now, it makes no difference. It still refuses all connections on port 1026.

Comment: @MikaelGuldborg could you reboot the VM in which Orion is installed and try again, please?

Comment: Rebooting the virtual machine from the Testbed portal fixes the issue like before the update.

Comment: @MikaelGuldborg, your last report seems to point to a rare case that has happended also some time to us. It seems to be related to some kind of resource exahustion at OS level but we haven't dig on the root causes yet. I would add a new answer to the question based on this experience. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If the previous answer doesn't solve the problem, rebooting the VM in which Orion is running could help (see comment at [Orion Context Broker stops responding after some hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386094/orion-context-broker-possible-memory-leak/23386178?noredirect=1#comment36021596_23386178)).

Comment: While this is a workaround, it's not a very nice one. And it is definitely not a solution we can use in production. Especially given that it happens relatively frequently. Is this an issue that is tracked on github, so I can follow when it is fixed?

Comment: @MikaelGuldborg As the particular cause has not been identified, we haven't created github issue yet. In this sense, any feedback that you could tell us about your environment would help. For example, in which OS are you running Orion? Which hw sizing it has? How often the problem happens? What is the Orion usage pattern and load (e.g. updateContext and queryContext per second, if you are using notification or just synchronous operations, etc)? Thanks!

Comment: Added some usage statistics in my initial question. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your usage information @MikaelGuldborg . However, I have two doubts. First, you mention that you send ~20 updateContext each 5 seconds. Are these updateContext requets updating existing entites or each updateContext creates a new entity? Second, after a reset of the system (i.e. VM reboot and starting the CB), how much time passes until it hangs in average? Thanks!

Comment: They are updates to existing entities. There are about ~40 different entities in total and ~100 different attributes in total. It is a bit hard to me to give an exact estimate to how long before it crashes but it is in less than 16 hours.